# Why this url pattern is not working?

Tags: python, django

```
from views import login
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  ***  (r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/login/$', login, name='login'),

)
```

showing me the syntax error in line ***.

`http://localhost:8000/{{ slug }}/login/` is the action url in form. I want to make it using Django `{ % url slug login % }` tag. But it also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `url()` function if you're using the name keyword:

```
url(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/login/$', login, name='login'),
```

And the order of parameters to the `{% url %}` tag has the url name first. So it should be:

```
{% url login slug %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tuple` literals don't have named arguments. Try [`url()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.defaults.url) instead.

```
    url(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/login/$', login, name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

the way u are using the {% url slug login %} is not the correct syntax
you have to write the name which you wrote in your urls for that template,
 i.e {% url login %}
This is according to your url, try this it will work.........