# Using named url patterns throws error in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django

I am using named url-patterns in my Django app, but it is failing and I don't know why. I have followed the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) but my app errors out when it reads **urls.py**.

This **works**:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from www.apps.newsletter.models import Newsletter
from www.apps.newsletter.views import index, detail

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/no(?P<q_no>\d+)/(?P<q_slug>[^.*]+)/$', detail),
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/no(?P<q_no>\d+)/$', index),
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/$', index),
    (r'^$', index),
)
```

But this **fails**:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from www.apps.newsletter.models import Newsletter
from www.apps.newsletter.views import index, detail

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/no(?P<q_no>\d+)/(?P<q_slug>[^.*]+)/$', detail, name='newsletter-detail'),
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/no(?P<q_no>\d+)/$', index),
    (r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/$', index),
    (r'^$', index),
)
```

I want to use named url patterns (so I can use {% url %} in my template), but Django doesn't seem to want to play nice. Any ideas? All I am doing is adding the arg **name=""** and it causes the error:

```python
SyntaxError at /newsletter/

invalid syntax (urls.py, line 6)
```

This urls.py is referenced by the parent urls.py:

```python
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^software/', include('www.apps.software.urls')),
    url(r'^newsletter/', include('www.apps.newsletter.urls')),
)
```

I am using Django version 1.4. TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why this url pattern is not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313932/why-this-url-pattern-is-not-working)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks - you are correct. Should I delete this question then?

Comment: It should get closed eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [the `url` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) to make use of the `name` parameter:

```
url(r'^vol(?P<q_vol>\d+)/no(?P<q_no>\d+)/(?P<q_slug>[^.*]+)/$', detail, name='newsletter-detail'),
```

In other words, there is a difference between using a tuple and the `url` function.

Btw, you don't need to have named url patterns to make use of the `url` template tag, you can just use the view's path instead, i.e. `{% url "app.views.myview" %}`

Comment: Thanks. Thought it must be something simple like that. Must remember to RTFM more thoroughly....